# What is more commonly used, (die Tür) "aufmachen" or "öffnen"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Is either of those more common (due to some subtle differences)?

> die Tür aufmachen

and

> die Tür öffnen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"aufmachen" is more colloquial: [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aufmachen).